# jQuery toggleSlide: show/hide block

Tags: jquery

I have the following code. 
I want to make my content slide, when I click on a certain button. Everything works perfect. The only problem is that if I have moltiple html contents like this they are all opening at the same time. Trying to do many different method and nothing really works.

**HTML**

```
<div class="show_hide oh db w1-ha pr">
    <div class="w1-ha db oh left"> 
        <span  dataleave="" class="click left db oh btn green-btn">Reply</span>
    </div>
    <div class="show_" style="display: none;">
        Hidden message
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.show_hide span.click').click(function() {
        var thiz = $(this);

        $('.show_hide .show_').slideToggle(300, function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            thiz.toggleClass('active');

            var thiz_ = $('.show_hide span.click.active');
            var getHtmlBtn = thiz_.html();

            if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $('.show_hide').addClass('active');
                thiz_.attr('dataleave', getHtmlBtn).html('Hide');
            } else {
                $('.show_hide').removeClass('active');
                var data__ = thiz_.attr('dataleave');
                thiz_.html(data__);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
 $('.show_hide .show_').slideToggle(300, function() {
```

to this:

```
  thiz.closest('.show_hide').find('.show_').slideToggle(300, function() {
```

---

You need to find the element in context of your selector. So `var thiz` is the clicked `span` and you can either traverse up to the closest parent and then you can find the element to slide.

---

As per your latest comment you can update to this:

```
$('.show_hide span.click').click(function () {
    var thiz = $(this),
        getHtmlBtn; // put a global var here

    thiz.closest('.show_hide').find('.show_').slideToggle(300, function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        thiz.toggleClass('active');

        var thiz_ = $('.show_hide span.click.active');
        getHtmlBtn = thiz.text(); // update here

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.show_hide').addClass('active');
            thiz_.attr('dataleave', thiz.text()).text('Hide');
        } else {
            getHtmlBtn = thiz.attr('dataleave'); // and again here;
            thiz.text(getHtmlBtn)
            $('.show_hide').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68bfshzc/)

Comment: you can add this to your answer thiz.parent().next().slideToggle(300, function()   :)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef you can do it. But `.closest() and .find()` performs better. Thanks though for suggestion.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef and one more thing i want to extend my last comment, if for some reason OP updates his/her markup like adding new elems before sliding element then `thiz.parent().next().slideToggle(300, function()` would fail.

Comment: There is a problem. Button doesn't return the value of data attribute back to the button.

Comment: When I found someone who don't know alot about jquery I suggest to give him more and more of options .. not just to solve his/her issue but I just thinking maybe he/she will need it later .. but I agree with you .. your answer is totally right :)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef don't get it wrong man, i just want to post better code only, but you are also right. You can edit my answer and explain a bit about it, hope this make sense.

Comment: This is nothing wrong bro.. I just explain to you how I thinking that's it .. cheerz :)

Comment: Guys, there is  problem with the button the receives the value of data attribute. It get's html('hide') but not getting the value of the button back.. What should do?

Comment: change to this: `var getHtmlBtn = thiz_[0].outerHTML;` or `var getHtmlBtn = thiz_.get(0).outerHTML;`

Comment: Still the same. Everything works fine, but html() doesn't return the value. Like: I get "Hide" in the button, but when I click on the button again, I don't get the value back from attr('dataleave');

Comment: so you want to change the text of the clicked element.

Comment: Jai, yes, If you look back at my code I am trying to put the value of button into the datalaeve attribute, so that I can store and replace the html in the button with text "hide". if you click on button that has "hide" text and attribute dataleave, it changes the html of the button the the value of dataleave. I hope you understood :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as I wanted ;) 
You are the best :) I votred for your answer :)